# How do I schedule an email to send at a certain time using cron and smtp, in python?

Tags: python, email, cron, smtp, smtplib

So far I have only been able to send emails. Here's my code:

```
import smtplib

email_user = 'myemail@gmail.com'
server = smtplib.SMTP ('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email_user, 'email pass')

#SET TIME HERE?
from crontab import CronTab

#EMAIL
message = 'sending this from python!'
server.sendmail(email_user, email_user, message)
server.quit()
```

I'm struggling to set a time to send the email. If someone can also help me figure out how to add attachments, that would be great!

Comment: What is your os?

Comment: Windows is my os

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you already have your `send_email()` function working I would do:

```
import datetime as dt
import time
import smtplib

def send_email():
    email_user = 'myemail@gmail.com'
    server = smtplib.SMTP ('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user, 'email pass')

    #EMAIL
    message = 'sending this from python!'
    server.sendmail(email_user, email_user, message)
    server.quit()

send_time = dt.datetime(2018,8,26,3,0,0) # set your sending time in UTC
time.sleep(send_time.timestamp() - time.time())
send_email()
print('email sent')
```

If you want to send the email regularly, you can do:

```
import datetime as dt
import time
import smtplib

def send_email():
    email_user = 'myemail@gmail.com'
    server = smtplib.SMTP ('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user, 'email pass')

    #EMAIL
    message = 'sending this from python!'
    server.sendmail(email_user, email_user, message)
    server.quit()

def send_email_at(send_time):
    time.sleep(send_time.timestamp() - time.time())
    send_email()
    print('email sent')

first_email_time = dt.datetime(2018,8,26,3,0,0) # set your sending time in UTC
interval = dt.timedelta(minutes=2*60) # set the interval for sending the email

send_time = first_email_time
while True:
    send_email_at(send_time)
    send_time = send_time + interval
```

You can also spawn a thread and leave this thread handle the sending of the email.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really new at this. Can you explain what the values mean inside the parentheses in line 4?

Comment: @Here the format is dt.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)

Comment: I'm getting the error that send_email is not defined.

Comment: That's why I wrote "assuming you already have your send_email() function working", just put your code to send the email under a send_email() function.

Comment: @Here great, please accept my answer so I can have enough points to comment on other people's questions :P

Answer (score 0):

Best way to send an email using CRON is to use Postfix and mailutils. Follow below steps to send email with cron job results/errors.

**Step 1 — Installing Postfix**

First, update the package database:

```
sudo apt update
```

Next, install mailtuils:

```
sudo apt install mailutils
```

Finally, install postfix:

```
sudo apt install postfix
```

Near the end of the installation process, you will be presented with a window that looks like the one in the image below. The default option is Internet Site. That’s the recommended option for this tutorial, so press TAB, then ENTER

**Select No Configuration**

[image: Select No Configuration]

**Step 2 — Configuring Postfix**

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Then paste below code on the empty file.

```
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only

mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$your_domain, $your_domain
```

Save and close the file.
Finally, restart Postfix.

```
sudo systemctl restart postfix
```

**Step 3 — Testing the SMTP Server**

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" your_email_address
```